How to simulate non-standardized artificial data for logistic regression?
I would like to simulate data for a logistic regression with the predictor variables on their original scale.
There are, of course, a litany of similar previous questions (e.g., here, here, and here). But my question focuses on manipulation of the inverse-link function.
Raw (Uncentered and Unscaled) X
A combination of predictors on their original scale with the standard inverse-link function produces outcomes that prevent recovery of the population beta values. Of course, I understand this particular issue is mainly that the inverse-link function is not matched to xb and is therefore producing values for p that are always almost or actually equal to 1. For example:
set.seed(42)

n <- 10000

betas <- c(1, 2, 3)

data <- data.frame(
  x1 = sample(c(0,1), size = n, replace = TRUE),
  x2 = round(runif(n, 18, 80)),
  x3 = rnorm(n, 100, 10)
)

# to be uncommented in the second example
#data$x2 <- scale(data$x2)
#data$x3 <- scale(data$x3)

x <- as.matrix(data)

xb <- x %*% betas
p <- 1 / (1 + exp(-xb))
data$y <- rbinom(n, 1, p)

glm(y ~ -1 + x1 + x2 + x3, data = data, family = "binomial") |>
  coef()
#> Warning: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
#>         x1         x2         x3 
#> 0.68776594 0.04537462 0.27567873

Created on 2024-04-17 with reprex v2.1.0
Scaled (Centered and Scaled) X
However, first scaling the continuous predictors prevents this issue. For example:
set.seed(42)

n <- 10000

betas <- c(1, 2, 3)

data <- data.frame(
  x1 = sample(c(0,1), size = n, replace = TRUE),
  x2 = round(runif(n, 18, 80)),
  x3 = rnorm(n, 100, 10)
)

data$x2 <- scale(data$x2)
data$x3 <- scale(data$x3)

x <- as.matrix(data)

xb <- x %*% betas
p <- 1 / (1 + exp(-xb))
data$y <- rbinom(n, 1, p)

glm(y ~ -1 + x1 + x2 + x3, data = data, family = "binomial") |>
  coef()
#>        x1        x2        x3 
#> 0.9732245 1.9205790 2.8166412

Created on 2024-04-17 with reprex v2.1.0
What I Have Tried

setting a population intercept to the negative mean of xb
centering and scaling xb
centering the inverse-link function on the mean of xb
centering and scaling the inverse-link function based on various statistics computed on xb

However, none of those approaches have allowed me to generate a simulated data set consisting of the predictors on their original scale combined with a response variable that can be easily and directly modeled by a logistic regression.
What I Would Like
Instead of scaling, I would like to understand how I might leverage either the intercept and/or modify the inverse-link function from its standard form in order to generate a distribution of values for p that then result in y values allowing for recovery of the population beta values. I suppose I am more interested in understanding how to manipulate the inverse-link function to "automatically" produce values for p with desirable properties.

Look at the distribution of true probabilities (p) in your first example. Do you think a model could come anywhere close to replicating your coefficients? You can't arbitrarily choose a scale for predictors and coefficients and assume that they represent a plausible model. The solution is to choose coefficients that are plausible for the scale of your variable. This has nothing to do with the link function. If all of the values for the linear predictor are extreme, all the probabilities will be, too, and no model will be able to recover your coefficients.

You can start with scaled predictors, then "un-standardize" them by multiplying them by your desired SD and dividing the chosen coefficient by that SD to retain the relationship between the predictor and the outcome.

How does this not address what you want to do? I consider that the go-to for a GLM simulation.

@Noah Yes, I was aware the distribution of true probabilities in the first example is ridiculous. I was hoping to generate a better distribution of values for p by manipulating the inverse-link function. But your point about needing to choose plausible coefficients is a good one. I will play around with your "un-standardize" approach. That might be what I am after.

@Dave That example is great, but notice that the predictors are all drawn from the standard normal. I would like to draw from normals other than the standard normal as well as other distributions entirely.

Feel free to change them to rnorm(1000, 7, 13) or rexp(1000, 4) or whatever. Nothing forces you to use those distributions. Is there something problematic downstream of such changes?

@Dave Yes, the problem is that arbitrarily combining scales for both predictors (e.g., using rnorm(1000, 7, 13)) and coefficients (e.g., my betas <- c(1, 2, 3)) produce values for p that are always either close to or actually equal to 1 whereas getting a good fitting logistic model requires a distribution of values for p with certain properties. One of the main properties being that not all values for p are 1.

Of course it does. Consider how many large values you get from $N(7, 13)$ and the probabilities corresponding to such values as log-odds.

You want simulated conditional probabilities that are not all bunched up by $1$ (or $0$). Work backward. The linear predictor of a logistic regression is the log-odds.
$$
\log\left(\dfrac{p}{1-p}\right)
$$
In order to have probability values that are in between, say, $0.1$ and $0.9$, you need log-odds values that are in between about $\pm 2$.
$$
\log\left(\dfrac{0.1}{1-0.1}\right) \approx -2\\
\log\left(\dfrac{0.9}{1-0.9}\right) \approx 2
$$
Therefore, your linear combination of predictors should stay within these bounds.
If you have a feature that is $N\left(7, 13^2\right)$-distributed (take $13$ as the standard deviation, as we did in the comments), many of the values will be above that upper bound of $2$. Indeed, pnorm(2, 7, 13) shows that only about a third of values will be below $2$.
Then you start adding up multiple positive features. You wind up with conditional log-odds that are large positive numbers. That will, of course, lead to conditional probability values that are close to $1$.
Everything is working as it should. You just need to pick better distributions or better coefficients to give log-odds values between about $-2$ and $2$.
Possible solutions:

Use a mix of positive and negative coefficients. Including negative coefficients on features that are mostly positive will decrease the log-odds when you do the linear combination.

Use smaller coefficients that do not lead to such extreme log-odds values the correspond to probability values near $0$ and $1$.

Simulate features that do not have huge values.


I combine all of these into the example below, which gives what I view as a reasonable set of conditional probability values.
set.seed(2024)
N <- 1000
x1 <- rexp(N, 3)
x2 <- runif(N, -3, 3)
Beta <- c(-0.5, 0.5)
z <- cbind(x1, x2) %*% Beta
p <- 1/(1 + exp(-z))
summary(p)
hist(p)

The probability values are between $0.07$ and $0.82$, with the middle half of the density ranging from $0.29117$ to $0.64076$, totally reasonable for a logistic regression.

If the issue is that all of the probabilities are near $1$ (not near $0$), then you can use a large negative intercept to give more reasonable log-odds values, demonstrated below.

set.seed(2024)
N <- 1000
x1 <- rnorm(N, 7, 3)
x2 <- rnorm(N, 7, 2)
Beta <- c(1, 1)
z <- cbind(x1, x2) %*% Beta - 15
p <- 1/(1 + exp(-z))
summary(p) 
hist(p, xlim = c(0, 1))

